# I have a syntax error that was not an issue before? This happened a bit after installing react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, syntax-error, react-icons

I've posted the code in question below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {FaGithub, FaLinkedin, FaCodepen} from 'react-icons/fa';
import {HiOutlineMailOpen} from 'react-icons/hi';
import {BsFillPersonLinesFill} from 'react-icons/bs';



const SocialLinks = () => {

    const links = [
        {
            id:1,
            child: (
                <>
                GitHub <FaGithub size={30}/>
                </>
            ),
            href: '(blank for purpose of posting here)',
            style: 'rounded-tr-md'
        },

        {
            id:2,
            child: (
                <>
                Codepen <FaCodepen size={30}/>
                </>
            ),
            href: '(blank for purpose of posting here)',
        },
```

This is an image of the error in the code:

[image]

This was not an issure before. Please help me resolve this.

Comment: I think some of the links fetched don't have the property 'style' defined

Comment: @NadirBelhaj - That did not resolve my problem. In the end I did my project over and now it works fine. Im not sure what happend in this case though.